# Conditional Probability in Multivariate Normal

Tags: multivariate-analysis, conditional-probability, integral

Given a tri-variate Normal, the conditional probability of an element given others truncated information is

[image]

Now if I know that the mean vector ***u*** is (-0.91,-1.31,-1.39) and ***R*** is

```
1      0.19   0.21
0.19    1     0.33
0.21   0.33     1
```

Is there a way to calculate analytically the probability? I don't want to pass through simulations

Comment: You should learn proper $\LaTeX$  syntax, such as \infty for $\infty$

Comment: ... and you should type in your equation, not copy an image!   What did you try?